# update from application doesnt execute the query but execution from url will execute the query

Tags: php, android

the query from the application is not being updated , but I can do it manually

this is the url , note if you exucte it , the query will be run

`http://justedhak.com/old-files/singleactivity.php?id=1&likes=14`

this is the php, i know php needs improvement

```
$id= intval($_GET['id']);
$likes= intval($_GET['likes']);

$con = mysqli_connect($host,$uname,$pwd,$db) or die(mysqli_error());
echo $id;

    $sql1="UPDATE OBJECTS SET LIKES=$likes WHERE ID=$id";
   $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql1);
```

this is the code

```
class SendPostReqAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected  void onPreExecute()
        {
            Log.e("GetText","called");

        }
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String json = "";

            try{
                RequestBody formBody = new FormEncodingBuilder()
                        .add("id", "1")
                        .add("likes", "10")
                        .build();
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("http://justedhak.com/old-files/singleactivity.php")
                        .post(formBody)
                        .build();

                Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
                //insert username, password and login true after successful login.


                //redirect to main activity


            } catch (IOException e){
                Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
            }

            return "success";
        }
```

I am not getting errors , and the asyctask looks good

Comment: I could not understood what is your problem. Can you detail a little more?

Comment: @jonathanrz i am executing the asynctask to update a column , but its not executing , from the app when i open this activity and execute the asytask , I go to the database and I see the value still the same , if i run the query manually it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API support only `GET` method. You don't need to create a `RequestBody` for that.

Try this,

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        String id = "1";
        String likes = "14";
        String url = "http://justedhak.com/old-files/singleactivity.php?id=" + id + "&likes=" + likes;
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .build();

        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

        if (!response.isSuccessful()){
            throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);
        }

        Log.e("MYAPP", response.body().string());

    } catch (IOException e){
        Log.e("MYAPP", "unexpected JSON exception", e);
    }

    return "success";
}
```

Try this code in `PHP`,

```
<?php
$id = intval($_GET['id']);
$likes = intval($_GET['likes']);

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($host, $uname, $pwd, $db);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "UPDATE OBJECTS SET LIKES=$likes WHERE ID=$id";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: the weird thing is in the url i am passing the parameter as integer , in the application i am sending them as string but in php i am converting them. possible thats the prblm?

Comment: I noticed something, where I have removed the where condition from query it worked. the problem is in condition

Comment: how to catch the error from php to be displayed on logcat?

Comment: I am having the error on php `Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/justdb/public_html/old-files/singleactivity.php on line 20` on this line if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

Comment: I fixed it was `$conn` but still i am not gettig anything from php and its not updating !!!!!

Comment: `Record updated successfully` is not being displayed in the logcat?

Comment: What is being printed? `Error updating record: `?

Comment: hi you still there?